# xinput Wheel Emulation properties have no effect

Tags: 13.04, mouse-scroll, xinput

On an Ubuntu 13.04 machine, I have the following input devices:

```
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB LaserStream(TM) Mouse        id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ CHICONY HP Basic USB Keyboard             id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

The default configuration of the mouse is:

```
$ xinput list-props 9
Device 'Logitech USB LaserStream(TM) Mouse':
    Device Enabled (143):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (145): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (273): 0
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (274):   1.000000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (275):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (276):    10.000000
    Device Product ID (262):    1133, 49272
    Device Node (263):  "/dev/input/event3"
    Evdev Axis Inversion (277): 0, 0
    Evdev Axes Swap (279):  0
    Axis Labels (280):  "Rel X" (153), "Rel Y" (154), "Rel Horiz Wheel" (271), "Rel Vert Wheel" (272)
    Button Labels (281):    "Button Left" (146), "Button Middle" (147), "Button Right" (148), "Button Wheel Up" (149), "Button Wheel Down" (150), "Button Horiz Wheel Left" (151), "Button Horiz Wheel Right" (152), "Button Side" (266), "Button Extra" (267), "Button Forward" (268), "Button Back" (269), "Button Task" (270), "Button Unknown" (265), "Button Unknown" (265), "Button Unknown" (265), "Button Unknown" (265)
    Evdev Middle Button Emulation (282):    0
    Evdev Middle Button Timeout (283):  50
    Evdev Third Button Emulation (284): 0
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Timeout (285): 1000
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Button (286):  3
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Threshold (287):   20
    Evdev Wheel Emulation (288):    0
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes (289):   0, 0, 4, 5
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia (290):    10
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout (291):    200
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Button (292): 4
    Evdev Drag Lock Buttons (293):  0
```

I can use `xinput set-prop 9 <num> <values>` to set some of the properties, e.g. the `Evdev Axis Swap` property. In this case, the changes apply immediately.

However, if I enter the following command, the value changes in the xinput output, but the scrolling behavior of the mouse stays the same:

```
xinput set-prop 9 289 0 0 5 4
```

The other `Wheel Emulation` properties have no effect, either. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For my mouse the emulation works (vertical-axis) even with the setting set to false...

Comment: Solved here http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227264/is-it-possible-to-tweak-input-from-touchpad

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's more like 
(for setting mouse speed on my system it's prop 11)

```
xinput set-prop 11 'Device Accel Constant Deceleration' 1
```

...in your case

```
 xinput set-prop 9 'Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes' 0, 0, 5, 4
```

I am no expert and you can always use Xchat to go to the #Ubuntu IRC channel and ask for help. Just pop in and state your question clearly, don't ask if you can ask, just state your question and be patient.